# Implementing ListAdapter for a RecyclerView Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-listadapter

I've done this successfully with a normal **ViewAdapter** but I can't seem to get it working with a **ListAdapter**.

Here is my **Fragment** that does most of the work:

```
class CrimeListFragment: Fragment() {

    //Required interface for hosting activities
    interface Callbacks {
        fun onCrimeSelected(crimeId: UUID)
    }

    private var callbacks: Callbacks? = null
    private lateinit var crimeRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private val crimeListViewModel: CrimeListViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CrimeListViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        callbacks = context as Callbacks?
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false)

        crimeRecyclerView =
            view.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view) as RecyclerView
        crimeRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        crimeRecyclerView.adapter = CrimeListAdapter(emptyList())

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        crimeListViewModel.crimeListLiveData.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer { crimes ->
                crimes?.let {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got crimes ${crimes.size}")
                    updateUI(crimes)
                }
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()

        callbacks = null
    }

    private fun updateUI(crimes: List<Crime>) {
        crimeRecyclerView.adapter = CrimeListAdapter(crimes)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): CrimeListFragment {
            return CrimeListFragment()
        }
    }

    private inner class CrimeHolder(view: View)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {

        private lateinit var crime: Crime
        private val titleTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.crime_title)
        private val dateTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.crime_date)
        private val solvedImageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.crime_solved)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun bind(crime: Crime) {
            this.crime = crime
            titleTextView.text = crime.title
            dateTextView.text = crime.date.toString()
            solvedImageView.visibility = if(crime.isSolved) {
                View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                View.GONE
            }
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            callbacks?.onCrimeSelected(crime.id)
        }
    }

    private inner class CrimeListAdapter(var crimes: List<Crime>)
        : ListAdapter<Crime, CrimeHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CrimeHolder {
            val view =
                layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false)

            return CrimeHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CrimeHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bind(crimes[position])
        }
    }

    private inner class DiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Crime>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Crime, newItem: Crime): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Crime, newItem: Crime): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the fragment's viewmodel:

```
class CrimeListViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val crimeRepository = CrimeRepository.get()
    val crimeListLiveData = crimeRepository.getCrimes() //returns LiveData<List<Crime>>
}
```

Android documentation has this regarding **ListAdapter**:

> While using a **LiveData** is an easy way to provide data to the adapter, it isn't required - you can use **submitList(List)** when new lists are available.

1. I'm supposed to submit a new list instead of creating a new **ListAdapter** object each time I update the UI. But `crimeRecyclerView.adapter` has no `.submitList()` function. So how do I pass on the new list?
2. **LiveData** is still new to me so I'm not quite clear on this. I already observe a **LiveData** stored in my viewmodel. So what do I observe this time? Or do I just add code to my existing **Observer**?
3. Finally when I run the code in this state, phone shows an empty **RecyclerView**. Only `UpdateUI()` gets called, none of `CrimeListAdapter`'s functions get called. I'm not sure if this is a real problem or just the consequence of the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.I'm supposed to submit a new list instead of creating a new ListAdapter object each time I update the UI. But
>   crimeRecyclerView.adapter has no .submitList() function. So how do I
>   pass on the new list?

`crimeRecyclerView.adapter` return RecyclerView.Adapter type

`submitList()` is a method of ListAdapter, a sub-class of RecyclerView.Adapter

You need to cast from super to sub class before calling that method, like this.

```
(crimeRecyclerView.adapter as CrimeListAdapter).submitList(crimes)
```

> 2.LiveData is still new to me so I'm not quite clear on this. I already observe a LiveData stored in my viewmodel. So what do I
>   observe this time? Or do I just add code to my existing Observer?

Your code for this part is good, no need to do more.

> 3.Finally when I run the code in this state, phone shows an empty RecyclerView. Only UpdateUI() gets called, none of CrimeListAdapter's
>   functions get called. I'm not sure if this is a real problem or just
>   the consequence of the above.

The best part of using ListAdapter is you do not need to provide a list of data (crimes in your case) to constructor.

Back to your code, you need to change 3 things.

```
// crimeRecyclerView.adapter = CrimeListAdapter(emptyList())
crimeRecyclerView.adapter = CrimeListAdapter()
```

and

```
// crimeRecyclerView.adapter = CrimeListAdapter(crimes)
(crimeRecyclerView.adapter as CrimeListAdapter).submitList(crimes)
```

and

```
//private inner class CrimeListAdapter(var crimes: List<Crime>) :
//    ListAdapter<Crime, CrimeHolder>(DiffCallback()) {
//
//    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CrimeHolder {
//        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false)
//        return CrimeHolder(view)
//    }
//
//    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CrimeHolder, position: Int) {
//        holder.bind(crimes[position])
//    }
//}

private inner class CrimeListAdapter : ListAdapter<Crime, CrimeHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CrimeHolder {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false)
        return CrimeHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CrimeHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}
```